# WCF hosting in IIS 7 using ASP.NET error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7

I have hosted a WCF service reference in IIS 7 and my wsdl path is

```
http://localhost:82/CustomService.Service1.svc as it is running **on Port 82**
```

I published my asp.net website in a folder and copied that folder to IIS 7 on **other port 81**
I can browse default.aspx but how can I invoke my WCF service from this website
my Web Config is as follows

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:82/CustomService.Service1/"    
   binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"   
   contract="MyServiceReference.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

When I try to run the service from ASP.net I get an error there was no endpoint at
     `http://localhost:82/CustomService.Service1` that could accept the message

Please help

Comment: if you add a web service reference please give full path URL

Comment: Yep as @N K said your endpoint address at your web.config is incorrect. http://localhost:82/CustomService.Service1.svc put the right address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your endpoint address seems incorrect. Replace it with

`http://localhost:82/CustomService.Service1.svc`